# Jest tests taking a long time to complete

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm looking to do a bit of cleaning up in our test suite and have come across this code:

```js
    const form = screen.getByTestId(elements.form);
    const firstName = screen.getByTestId(elements.firstName);
    const lastName = screen.getByTestId(elements.lastName);
    const email = screen.getByTestId(elements.email);
    const password = screen.getByTestId(elements.password);
    const confirmPassword = screen.getByTestId(elements.confirmPassword);
    const telephone = screen.getByTestId(elements.telephone);
    const dobDay = screen.getByRole('option', { name: '05' });
    const dobMonth = screen.getByRole('option', { name: 'April' });
    const dobYear = screen.getByRole('option', { name: '1990' });

    userEvent.type(firstName, 'TestingFirstName');
    userEvent.type(lastName, 'TestingLastName');
    userEvent.type(email, 'testing@email.com');
    userEvent.type(password, 'Password123');
    userEvent.type(confirmPassword, 'Password123');
    userEvent.type(telephone, '07888888888');
    userEvent.click(dobDay);
    userEvent.click(dobMonth);
    userEvent.click(dobYear);
```

These  queries and actions are repeated several times within the same describe block, which results in each test taking 7-10 seconds to run.  Overall doubling the length of time our entire suite takes to run.

Is there a way to streamline this, so it only runs the above a single time?  Or caches the above for quicker use next time around?  Or anything that'll speed things up a little?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean that the whole code block above is repeated? If so why?

Comment: @Christian Yes - It's not my code, I just saw that the tests for the code in question were taking close to a minute to complete so wanted to take a closer look to understand why.

So due to the above being repeated several times, it takes a large amount of time to complete.  But I don't think even a single test should realistically take 7-10 seconds to complete?  So was hoping I could fix two birds with one stone.  I'm just unsure where to start

Comment: GUI tests can often take quite some time but 7-10 seconds sounds a bit much. I would start by trying to understand why they are being repeated (unless it tests different screens each time?)
A dirty fix would be to set a flag indicating that it has executed and then prevent consecutive runs.

Comment: @Christian I guess with each test, the component is cleaned up and re-rendered, so the actions have to be ran again.  I was under the impression that it may be the queries taking up a lot of time, but it's actually the userEvents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` instead of `type`.  The `paste` function is much faster than the `type` function.